# $selected attribute not working in codeigniters form_dropdown()

Tags: forms, codeigniter, selected, html-select

I have an editform with a dropdown for choosing a category.
I also made a function for getting the category from the database.

I set an array `$opties` for the dropdown to select form and a 'selected' parameter called `$selectie` this one contains the category for that specific company in the database.

It looks like this:

```
<tr>
<td><?= form_label('Categorieen'); ?></td>
<td><?= form_dropdown('categorieen', $opties, $selectie); ?></td>
</tr>
```

**Question**

Why is my 'selected' part not working?

When I do a `print_r($selectie)` I get:

```
Array
(
    [12] => Vlaggen
)
```

which is my category in the database.

When I do a `print_r($opties)` I get:

```
Array
(
    [11] => Webdesign
    [12] => Vlaggen
    [13] => Auto-s
    [14] => Electronica
    [15] => Boeken
    [16] => Antiek-en-Kunst
    [17] => Auto-Onderdelen
    [18] => Computers-Hardware
    [19] => Computers-Software
)
```

I don't know what the problem is.
Some help would be appreciated.

**Controller:**

```
function updatebedrijven()
{
    $dbres = $this->db->get('categorieen');
    $ddmenu = array();
    foreach ($dbres->result_array() as $tablerow) {
        $ddmenu[$tablerow['idcategorieen']] = $tablerow['Categorie'];
    }
    $data['opties'] = $ddmenu;
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3); 
    $id2 = $this->uri->segment(3); 

    $data['selected'] = $this->members_model->getselection($id2);

    $data['info'] = $this->members_model->getbedrijf($id); 
    $data['id'] = $id;
    $this->load->view('members/header');
    $this->load->view('members/editform', $data);
    $this->load->view('members/footer');    
}
```

**Model:**

```
//This one is for the $opties

function getbedrijf($id) 
{ 
    $this->db->where('idbedrijven', $id); 
    $query = $this->db->get('bedrijven'); 

    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) { 
    $row = $query->row_array(0); 

    return $row; 
    } 
}

//This one is for the $selectie

function getselection($id2)
{
    $this->db->from('bedrijfcategorieen');
    $this->db->join('categorieen', 'bedrijfcategorieen.idcategorieen = categorieen.idcategorieen');
    $this->db->where('bedrijfcategorieen.idbedrijven', $id2);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`form_dropdown` uses the arrays `key => value` as its `'value' and 'option'`,
to select a data from your dropdown you will need the key of your selected data for example you choose

`[12] => Vlaggen` to select it you need its key which is `12`, and not an array like

```
Array
(
    [12] => Vlaggen
)

<? 
//just for testing
echo form_dropdown('categorieen', $opties, key($selectie)); 
?>
```

Comment: A case of [RTFM](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Comment: so i just need the id. that's possible.